# Set focus to specific window of an application using applescript

Tags: applescript

How can I set focus to a specific window of a given application using applescript?

I have several iTerm2 windows running on different displays. I want to set focus to a specified window using applescript.

I need two things, one script that collects the window ID's and prints them to stdout. I've got this:

```
tell application "iTerm"
  set wins to id of every window
end tell
```

which prints 6 integers: 3034, 2528, -1, -1, -1, -1

Bonus Question: What are the four -1's ?

Then I try:

```
tell application "System Events"
  activate window 3034
end tell
```

Upon which the only thing happening is that I lose focus of my current terminal (in which I am typing these commands), not matter whether I specify 3034 or 2528 as the ID.

Comment: Check out [this question on Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39204/script-to-raise-a-single-window-to-the-front); if you combine `perform action "AXRaise" of someWindow` with `tell application "The Application" to activate`, you'll get what you want.  But the caveat (and reason this isn't an answer) is that you can't seem to specify windows by window ID this way (which makes sense, as if I understand correctly, window IDs are application-specific).  Bonus question: the -1s are probably things like preference/find dialogs, which may or may not even be visible.

Answer (score 2):

You almost have it.  You can filter out the "-1" window IDs as by only looking at visible windows:

```
tell application "iTerm 2"
  set wins to id of every window whose visible is true
end tell
```

I figured this out by looking at the results of:

```
tell application "iTerm 2" to properties of every window
```

I noticed that the "-1" windows have the property `visible:false`

Then you can tell the window ID directly to the iTerm application instead of system events:

```
tell application "iTerm 2"
  activate window 13195
end tell
```

Comment: i wish this worked for me, but instead it just activates the last active window of the given application.

Comment: Any news after years? :)