# The Focus of the Default Sharing Window

Tags: macos, cocoa, window, focus

I'm using a command-line tool called terminal-share to use the macOS's system sharing service.

The tool's code can be found here:
https://github.com/mattt/terminal-share/

But, there is one little problem with this tool. Since this is a headless command-line application it doesn't have any windows of its own.

And when invoking it (using NSSharingService), it will start a sharing window(the default sharing window), but the sharing window won't have any focus.

So, I must click the post button using the mouse, not by using the CMD + SHIFT + D (or CMD + Enter) to send the share. Since there is no focus(the window that accepts for the key event still is the terminal emulator that starts this application.

This is quite annoying. Is there any better way to fix this?

I've investigated the NSSharingService API, it didn't have any code about the default sharing window. Is there any way just to keep this tool headless, and let the default sharing window become focused when it comes out?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, not familiar with the NSSharingService, but would it be an option to get Automator ([example](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34828)) or Apple's osascript ([example](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/117790)) to do it for you? EDIT: You might also like to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15101541/4041795). Let me know if it helped ok? Thnx!